# asp.net mvc + Ajax.BeginForm OnBegin not firing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

After reading several posts regarding this issue, it is mostly related to including

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

and the proper order of including jquery first.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

I think I did properly, but OnBegin is not firing still.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

<title>Test</title>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>    

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

So the order of process is:

School View:

```
@model Test.Models.School

<div class="editorRow">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("schools"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("New Employee", "NewEmployee", "Test", new
   {
       @class = "btn btn-info btn-md",
       data_toggle = "modal",
       data_target = "#modal-container-employee"
   })   
</div>

<div id="modal-container-employee" class="modal fade" tableindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult NewEmployee()
    {
        var newEmployee = new Employee();

        return View(newEmployee);
    }
```

Employee view:

```
@model Test.Models.Employee

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostEmployee", "Employee", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,       
    OnBegin = "closeModal"
}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div id="test" class="">
    <div class="modal-title title">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" /><span id="closes">x</span>
    </div>               
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)    
</div> 
}

<script>
    function closeModal() {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');          
    }
</script>
```

controller:

```
 [HttpPost]    
    public ActionResult PostEmployee(Employee model)
    {
        try
        {
            var newEmployee = new Employee
            {                    
                FullName = model.FullName
            };

            db.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(new { status = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "error", errorMessage = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

As a result, "success" Json is returned, but ajax is not catching it, it directly goes to the other page where it shows JSON array {"status":"success"}.
Can anyone find the problem?

Comment: Do you have a `@section scripts { ..` section in the view that might be adding another copy of `jquery-{version.js`?

Comment: And where is the element with `id="modal-container"`?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, there is no duplication for jquery in my project other than _Layout page. I've edited my question, and i'd appreciate it if you can take a look at it.

Comment: If submitting the form results in a redirect that displays the `JsonResult`, it means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not working (and a normal submit is being made). Check if there are any errors in you browser console (possible there is a corrupt file, or an issue with versions). In any case, the `Ajax.BeginForm()` and `Ajax.ActionLink()` are effectively obsolete and you would be far better off just using the `$.ajax()` methods (and save the extra overhead of loading that file)

Comment: There are no corrupt files and errors. And what does it mean by obsolete? Any example that I can use it  without using beginform or action link?

Comment: Its not even supported in MVC-6. Use `Html.BeginForm()` ( or just `<form>`) and `$('form').submit(function() { $.ajax({ .... }); return false; });`

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, that one little piece of advice fixed my problem.